# Append an element to the top of an inverted FlatList

Tags: react-native, socket.io, chat, flatlist

I'm currently working on a React Native Chat App and I am trying to display the chat messages in a conventional way. I am using the Expo CLI along with Socket.io and my messages FlatList looks like following:

```
<FlatList
    ref={chatRef}
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
    inverted
    onEndReached={loadMore}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
/>

const onContentSizeChange = () => {
    chatRef.current.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 })
}
```

My chat is working as expected and well displayed but whenever I send a new message it's been appended at the top of the FlatList.

When a new chat is sent, I dispatch an action to my reducer and I add the message as following:

```
{...}
case ADD_MESSAGE: return {
    ...state,
    messages: [...state.messages, action.payload]
}
{...}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to append the new message at the end of the FlatList and scroll to the end of it.

Note: My messages array is order by **newest** to **oldest**

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlatList` has a `scrollToIndex` method: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to tell how you're reacting to props changes, but assuming you're using hooks, you could do something like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  chatRef.current.scrollToIndex({{animated: true, index: messages.length - 1}})
},[messages])
```

That *should* scroll to the last message.  If you want it to scroll to the first one, go to `index: 0`.

Regarding the order of your messages array, it seems like you have conflicting information; you said that it's ordered newest -> oldest, but in your action, you show `[...state.messages, action.payload]` which would seem to take the *newest* message onto the end of it.  However, you can always switch the order (`[action.payload,...state.messages]`)

Regarding `inverted` as one of the parameters to your list:  I haven't experimented with this, but documentation says it "Reverses the direction of scroll." May want to be careful with how this affects your perception of ordering as well.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I will try the scrollToIndex method and validate your answer asap. I probably misspoke regarding the order of messages and will check that as well. As of the inverted prop I think I set it to true because my data was showing messages from newest to oldest and from top to bottom. Now everything is showing from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

When updating your messages array, append the new message to the start

```
messages: [ action.payload, ...state.messages]
```